# Solving an Exponential or Gaussian Integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, gaussian-integral

I am trying to solve a definite integral of the form
$$\int_c^\infty \frac{1}{x}e^{\Large -\frac{1}{2}(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma})^2}dx$$
where $\mu$, $\sigma$, and $c$ are real constants and $c>0$. This integral appears nowhere in [Wikipedia's list of integrals of Gaussian functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_Gaussian_functions).

When $\mu=0$ the indefinite form of the integral [is given by](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+1%2F%28x%29*exp%28-0.5*%28%28x%29%2Fsigma%29%5E2%29+dx)
$$\int \frac{1}{x}e^{\Large -\frac{1}{2}(\frac{x}{\sigma})^2}dx = 0.5Ei(-\frac{0.5x^2}{\sigma^2})+C_1$$
where $Ei$ is the [exponential integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral). The solution to the definite integral [is then](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+from+c+to+infinity+1%2F%28x%29*exp%28-0.5*%28%28x%29%2Fsigma%29%5E2%29+dx)
$$\int_c^\infty \frac{1}{x}e^{\Large -\frac{1}{2}(\frac{x}{\sigma})^2}dx = 0.5 \Gamma(0, \frac{c^2}{2\sigma^2})$$

where $\Gamma$ is the incomplete Gamma function. However, Wolfram Alpha is unable to simplify the integral when $\mu\neq0$.

I also tried Wolfram Mathematica, which did not return any results after running for 2 hours:

```
(*Assume all expressions are real*)
$Assumptions = _ \[Element] Reals && c > 0
Integrate[1/(x)*Exp[-0.5*((x-mu)/sigma)^2], {x, c, Infinity}]
```

At this point I'm not sure whether there is a simplified solution. I have a computer code that needs to evaluate the integral thousands-to-millions-of-times for various values of $\mu$ and $\sigma$, so it would be nice to have a solution that can be calculated quickly and accurately.

Comment: Essentially reduceable to:
$$\int_b^\infty \frac{e^{-x^{2}}}{x+a}dx$$
Though I donot know how to solve this form.

Comment: @BlackEmperor I also tried that form, but Wolfram Mathematica was just as stumped as before. Thanks for the effort though :)